# Confirmation code wont copy to phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Ok, my problem is that when i try to make my confirm link with the random code that i already created, it wont pass to the Confirmation mail. However the confirm code, still inserts to the database without problems. This is my code:

```
 function NewUser()
    {
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $confirm = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));


    $success = "INSERT INTO members(user,pass,'$confirm')";
    $data = mysql_query ($success)or die(mysql_error());
    if($data)
    {if($data)
    {
     SendUserConfirmationEmail($confirm);   
    echo "<div class ='verdanacenter'><img src='img/bienvenido.png' title='Enhorabuena'/><br><br><br><font face ='verdana'>Welcome <b>$name $lname</b> !!!<br>Success.<br><br>Soon u will receive a confirmation msg to <b>$email</b>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<div class ='verdanacenter'><img src='img/alerta.png' title='Error'/><br><br><br><font face ='verdana'>Fatal Error !!!";
    }
}

    function SendUserConfirmationEmail($confirmcode)
    {   
    require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->isSendmail();
    $mail->setFrom('info@rene.org', 'Rene');
    $mail->addAddress($_POST['email'],$_POST['name']);
    $mail->Subject = 'Welcome';
    $mail->IsHTML(true);    
    $confirmcode = $confirm;
    $mail->Body = '<p align="left"> Welcome <b>'.$_POST['name'].'</b>,</p><p align="justify">This is ur confirmation code:</p>
                                        <p align="left"><a href="http://www.rene.org/confirmar.php?code='.$confirmcode.'">CONFIRMAR</a>,</p>
                                        <p align="left">Regards,<br>
                                          Admin.<br>
                                          www.rene.org</p>';
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo "Message sent!";
    }
        }
```

The thing is that, when i register, i receive the email, but without the random code ($confimcode). It appears: "http://www.rene.org/confirmar.php?code=" instead of "http://www.rene.org/confirmar.php?code=A23B45423545V6764542543" What am i missing guys? PLEASE HELP.

Comment: You're putting a function inside a function and you are wondering why you are having scope issues?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938170/accessing-a-variable-defined-in-a-parent-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called scope.

The function can't see variables from outside of itself. To pass that code to the function you include it in a parameter:

```
function SendUserConfirmationEmail($confirmcode){
...
```

when you call the function you pass your variable:

```
SendUserConfirmationEmail($confirm);
```

Anywhere inside your function, that value will be available as `$confirmcode`

Edit: Also just noticed you have a function inside a function. Don't do that, just make them separate.

Comment: check it again, the thing is that the function was big enough, so i had to delete some data, i skipped the last "}". They r separate functions.

Comment: That's fine but you still need to pass your variable to the function as a parameter. Functions only see their own variables by default.

Comment: I just modified it, and i still get the problem. function SendUserConfirmationEmail($confirmcode){
 and SendUserConfirmationEmail($confirm);

Comment: did you also remove the line that reassigns $confirmcode inside the function? there is no $confirm inside the function so you can't set anything to = that

Comment: i edited the code, take a look, really dont know witch function u r telling me.